# Access a variable declared in one file in anothe file in VC++. (Extern keyword usage)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, global-variables, extern

I have a VC++ solution (using VS2008)  with 2 projects Project A & project B.

Everything I discuss below is wrt Project A.

Project A has a sourec file a.cpp & it includes a header file "a.h". 
"a.h" has a variable int varA; which is modifies inside a.cpp.

```
a.cpp:
int varA = x*2;
// also do some calculations with varA in a.cpp
```

Now there is one more sourec file b.cpp in the same project A. And now lets say this "b.cpp" also includes same header file "a.h".
i.e

```
b.cpp
int varB = varA; // If I want to access varA & get the current value of varA here in b.cpp what should do ? Will it work if I declare varA as extern in a.h & include
```

**Here it's important to note that I wnat to not only access the variable varA from within b.cpp but also want to access the current value of this variable as updated by a.cpp.**

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to access the variable `varA` in `b.cpp` ***after*** it has been modified in `a.cpp`?

Comment: Are these variables global or within a function?

Answer (score 2):

Create a header file
A.h

```
extern int varA;
```

In A.cpp declare variable

```
int varA;
```

Include "A.h" in b.cpp

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable in some header file and then include this header to cpp file where you want to use it.